# Uninstalling Jupyter notebook from mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried uninstalling jupyter notebook from mac, I am getting this error.

```
source: no such file or directory: /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.rich.console import (
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    _IMPORT_CWD = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I dont understand the error. if anyone can help me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

The

> no such file or directory: /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate

means that this path was not found. There could be two technical reasons. On the one hand, it possibly does not exist at the time you try to reach it, and, on the second hand, it's possible that the user with whom you attempt to reach it you lack the necessary privileges to do so at the time. The

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Means that an operation is not permitted. So, you will need to find out whether the path exists and whether the user has access to it. It's very much possible that you just need to do it with the root user.